# Convert List(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)) to another class (Dependency Injection)

Tags: vb.net

I use Dependency Injection for my Project. There I have the following structure:

- Database Project
- DataClass Project (holds POCO classes)
- Contracts
- Program

The DataClass Project holds the POCO classes, which will get exchanged between the Program and the Database Project. Therefore, I have a contract like this:

```
Function GetLensRanges(criteria As List(Of Func(Of Sf6LensRangeIS, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of Sf6LensRangeIS)
```

On program side, I use Code like this:

```
Public Function GetLensRanges(criteria As List(Of Func(Of Sf6LensRangeIS, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of Sf6LensRangeIS)
    Dim locQuery = GetRepository()
    Return locQuery.GetLensRanges(criteria)
End Function
```

And:

```
locDataBaseCriteria.Add(Function(locQuery) locPrism * 100 <= locQuery.PrsToIS)

Dim locDiameters = From locQuery 
                   In locBusinessLayer.GetLensRanges(locDataBaseCriteria).ToList 
                   Order By locQuery.DiamIS
```

In DatabaseProject side I use the Interface:

```
Public Function GetLensRanges(criteria As List(Of Func(Of Sf6LensRangeIS, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of Sf6LensRangeIS)
    Implements ISF6Repository.GetLensRanges
```

And here is the Problem:
The Sf6LensRangeIS class Comes from the DataClass Project. This is 1:1 the same class, as it is used in DatabaseProject with one difference the POCO classes and members have all the Prefix "IS" and the DatabaseProject not.
So, on Database Project side, the Class Name is: Sf6LensRange

Now my question: How can I convert the

```
List(Of Func(Of Sf6LensRangeIS, Boolean))
```

to:

```
List(of Func(Of Sf6LensRange, Boolean))
```

Comment: purely theoric so only in comment : If both classes had impleted the same interface (say `ISf6LensRange`) that could have been easy. There maybe have a conversion operator from/to the classes but that introduce depency ; less invasive a method (example below that method is name `Range2RangeIS`) "somewhere" which takes one and construct the other from it ; and then map (with `List(Of T).ConvertAll`) your list with that method something along `newList = curList.ConvertAll(Function(f) Function(range) f(Range2RangeIS (range)))`

Comment: Hey
THX for your answer. 
In my case, I don't use Interface for this "Senior" class.
In my specific case, I try to achieve to have a random "where", depending on some conditions on Client side. This is why I Hand over the "func(of Sf6LensRangeIS, boolean)".

I think, I have to get the complete Expression tree and translate it from one class to another. 
But I don't know, how this should work.
THX